# Yahtzee probability calculations with arbitrary numbers of dice.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I'm working on a tabletop roleplaying game (think D&D) that's got (to my knowledge) a novel mechanic.

So the central game mechanic is essentially lifted from Yahtzee: characters want X of a kind or a straight of X dice with adjacent values in a row, but they also need to do this Y times in a particular roll of N dice.

The dice pool is of variable size, represented as N. We just going to care about the result of the first roll.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any way to program this for something like AnyDice, and while I wasn't bad at math in high school I primarily did math in high school so I wouldn't have to do it in college.

With that said, here's the insight that I've gotten so far:

Every possible combination that yields X in a straight or row is acceptable, so you've got a pretty good chance of having at least some straights or rows, even with the system minimum of three dice.

X*Y will likely be a significant factor; if you want X>=3, Y>=1 in a pool of 3, your chances are roughly 6% (between the three of a kinds [6/216] and three-length straights [6/216] that are possible, but my math may be off here when doing the permutations). I believe that trying the same thing with X>=1, Y>=3 is the same calculation (e.g. you'd need results like 2, 4, 6 or 1, 3, 5). You also have the opportunity to have X>=2, Y>=2, which works out to something like 10-12% (I tested this by hand because I have no clue how to calculate this. Obviously if X or Y is greater than the number of dice (N) there is 0 chance of success, because you can't roll four of a kind with 3 dice, but X+Y>N still leads to some successes, and actually more than X=N or Y=N. Where X+Y=N or even is greater than N without being too extreme, there is still a chance for success.

If a particular result would count in multiple ways, it is acceptable: for instance, rolling 3, 4, 4, 4, and 5 would satisfy X=>3 and Y=>2.

I think this would need a matrix to represent potential probabilities, but I'm also pretty sure that there's a handy formula to calculate the probability of a result given X, Y, and N that I'm just unaware of.

Is there a way for me to find a formula that would simply permit a relative dunderhead to plug those values into software or a calculator to get an idea of the matrix? I had a physics/math major roommate in college, and this looks very much like the sort of thing that he would've used MatLab to graph in 3d, but I don't even know how to do that.

Comment: To clarify, the groups are not allowed to overlap? So, if $X=3$, $Y=2$ and $N=6$, then `3 3 3 4 5 1` would not count as a success?

Comment: Overlapping is permitted.

Comment: Then I need more clarification. How many runs of three are there in the roll `1 1 2 2 3 3`? I would say there are eight; if you number the dice $1,2,3,4,5,6$ from left to right, then the selections $(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5)(1,4,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)$ of dice all have the faces `1 2 3`. Do you agree with my count? If so, the overlaps can get very complicated. Also, if you rolled `1 1 1 1 1 1`, there would be $\binom{6}3=20$ three of a kinds.

Comment: 1 1 2 2 3 3 would be a run of 3.

Dice can only be used in one straight; you don't get two straights of 3 if you have 1 2 3 4.

Comment: Same thing goes to matching; you check the dice pool once for matches and once for straights, then you're done.